# Pandas Python new column dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I have problems with initializing a new column in a dataframe, called df
I want to do:

```
df['new_column'] = 0
```

to have all values to zero..

But then is gives me:

> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try using `.loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value` instead

.. so, when I then want to work on it it **** up...

I looked up on the net but didn't really find something useful..
I am a beginner in pandas so sorry if the answer is obvious but I really don't know how to do this basic thing..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing this is because your df is already a view on some other dataframe like:

```
df = DF.iloc[100:]
```

in this case pandas will not really copy the data but just keep a reference to the old one. In my mind this is not very transparent and I have shot myself in the foot a couple of times with that.

a work around is to enfoce a copy of the dataframe to be sure it owns its own data:

```
df = df.copy()
```

so in your case you might want to do:

```
df = df.copy()
df['new_column'] = 0
```

I hope that does the trick for you

Comment: You're the one! Thanks a lot!